# my storyboard skips some keyframes

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I would like to swing an ellipse to one place and then shrink it. After the first storyboard stops, I intend to stretch the ellipse with the ellipse. However the shrinking process doesn't work at all. Hard to firgure out why~  Any help or tips will be appreciated. Thanks~

```
     <Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Swing" Duration="0:0:7">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="Leg" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="27.081"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="-25.783"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="Leg">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:6" Value="489.676"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="Leg">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:6" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:7" Value="0.2"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Swing2" BeginTime="0:0:7">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="Leg">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.2"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Swing_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource Swing}"/>
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Swing_BeginStoryboard1" Storyboard="{StaticResource Swing2}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Ellipse x:Name="Leg" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="156,204,0,147" Stroke="Black" Width="33" RenderTransformOrigin="0.464,-0.014">
        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="27.081"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    </Ellipse>
</Grid>
```

If I change the second storyboard as below, the ellipse will be shinking from the beginning.

```
 <Storyboard x:Key="Swing2">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="Leg">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:7" Value="0.2"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:9" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

Comment: The reason why I don't combine the two storyboard is that I would like the swing process (RotateTransform) keep repeating for a while. However, if I set the "duration" to it, the repeation will not work again. Another problem occurs....